# C# and ASP - Setting a command argument, then command argument disappearing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use a gridviewcommand to delete an entry in the gridview (as well as from the datacontext), but I want to ask the user to confirm or not first. I have a seperate linkbutton to execute the delete code using the ID of the item in the row that the user clicked the delete button in.

When the user clicks delete, my codebehind sets the CommandArgument property of the other linkbutton to basically be the same command argument that it passed. But when the user goes to confirm the deletion, all of a sudden the commandargument of the confirmation link is an empty string? Is the property being flushed after the first postback?

Here is my code:

ASPX

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TheId") %>' /> //Delete LinkButton

<asp:LinkButton ID="confirmDelete" runat="server" OnClick="confirmDelete_Click" Text="Delete" /> //Confirmation Button
```

C#

```
rowCommandFunction(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     // blah blah blah
     ...
     confirmDelete.CommandArgument = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     ...// I've put a breakpoint here, and it is setting the value properly...
}

confirmDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...but when this line tries to run, comfirmDelete.CommandArgument is set to an empty string?
    int selectedId = int.Parse(confirmDelete.CommandArgument);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the **second post back causes** the issue..

I think you should **remove the confirmDelete button** and instead **call a javascript function from lbDelete** and show a confirm box from there. Then perform your delete operation inside the command event.

see the code below,

Aspx section,

```
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TheId") %>' OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete()"/>
```

JavaScript section,

```
      function ConfirmDelete()
      {
         if(confirm("Are you sure to delete?"))
         {
             return true;
          }
           else
          {
            return false;
          }

      }
```

Comment: @Jordan I agree. If your intent was only to show a confirm message, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable the view state with `EnableViewState="True"` in the buttons.

By default buttons don't have the view state enabled, so you get the command argument disappearing after the postback, as you supposed.

Edit:

why don't set a `CommandName` to the second button and handle it in the RowCommand function?